# Animate logo to go left right from a center point

Tags: ios, uiview

I am an absolute beginner when using UIView animations. All I need to do is move an imageView from it's starting position 40 point to the right and the a position 40 points to the left of the initial position. And this should repeat on and on..

```
- (void)animateLogo
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.Logo.frame.origin.y, 10.0, self.Logo.frame.size.width, self.Logo.frame.size.height);
                         self.Logo.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

All this does is move it up down not left right . I tried setting the X parameter to 10 but no change ....
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
//note that this rect has x = 0
// you don't have to set this startRect if you created your logo in storyboard
CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[self.Logo setFrame:startRect];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     //note that this x is  +40
                     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.Logo.frame.origin.x + 40, self.Logo.frame.origin.y, self.Logo.frame.size.width, self.Logo.frame.size.height);
                     self.Logo.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming your Logo is an `UIImageView`, try creating the Logo programmatically:

```
CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(318, 47, 133, 97);
UIImageView *LogoImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:startRect];
[LogoImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected_image.png"]];
[LogoImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     //note that this x is  +40
                     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(LogoImage.frame.origin.x + 40, LogoImage.frame.origin.y, LogoImage.frame.size.width, LogoImage.frame.size.height);
                     LogoImage.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[self.view addSubview:LogoImage];
```

Comment: I'd appreciate you accepting this answer if it worked. Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand why but it's still moving on a diagonal ... all I need is an x axis translation ...  I changed the startRect to have the same y as the logo but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: whats the size and x y origin of your Logo frame?

Comment: x = 318 y = 47 w = 133 h = 97

Comment: Try creating the Logo programmatically, and make sure that the original size of you Logo is not offscreen. See my updated answer for creating the Logo programmatically

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is defining a new CGRect Frame, with the following properties (x coord,y coord, width, height)

You tell the self.Logo.frame, okay, I want you to move to the new coordinates (with identical width/height) in 2.0 seconds.

To get it to 'do the right thing', you'll want to give it proper x,y coordinates. One way to debug this will be to NSLog the current x,y coordinates of the self.logo.frame.origin.x, and y.

Comment: This app uses auto layout ... could that interfere with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `y` coordinate where you should be giving `x`. The definition of `CGRectMake` is, `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`. Change your code to:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, self.Logo.frame.origin.y,self.Logo.frame.size.width,self.Logo.frame.size.height);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: It moves on the diagonal for some reason

Comment: This totally depends on where you want to go and where you are right now. If you want the view to move horizontally, set the `x` coordinate to its current position and change the `y` coordinate.

`CGRect frame = CGRectMake(320 - self.Logo.frame.origin.x , self.Logo.frame.origin.y,self.Logo.frame.size.width,self.Logo.frame.height`

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want to have repeated animation, `CABasicAnimation` will be much better option. It works on layers and you will have much better control if you wish to stop animation in future.

If you go with the present approach, you will have to call the same method again inside your `completion` block (if you wish to stop animation in future) which can sometimes make your application little non-responsive depending upon what other processes are running.

I am not really clear in which way you want the animation of your image view to be, but if I have got it correctly you just want to move your image left to right and right to left. If you have more breaks with different durations, I would suggest you to make use of `CAKeyFrameAnimation`. I am enclosing some basic code on `CABasicAnimation`.

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.autoreverses = YES;
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.myImageView.center];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.myImageView.center.x + 40.f, self.myImageView.center.y)];
anim.duration = 2.f;

[self.myImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"imageViewAnim"];
```

To read more about `CABasicAnimation`, here is the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html)

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: You are wrong. You need not have to call the same method in the completion block. Set the options to `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and it will repeat itself.

Comment: @Avismara, I was referring to different context and was speaking of flexible programming. Currently I have edited the answer.